# Background IMG does not work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a background into the menu section in the top of my webpage... I have uploaded it to www.ra3manifesto.co.nf
I want a logo, h1 and the menu bar to be set on a background that I put in my images file. I have tried to place this background with the  following CSS code:

```
.hoofd {
background: url("includes/images/achtergrond.png");
}
```

There seems to be nothing wrong with the url (to demonstrate this I have placed the image that I want to use inside the second container div and it clearly shows on the webpage) but still the background image does not appear!!! I have been breaking my brains over this one for the last hour, who will come to my rescue :(

Comment: Are you sure you spelled the class correctly in the element?

Comment: Please include all relevant code so we can see how it's being used

Comment: try background-image. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

check the class name properly

Check image path url properly

Comment: Please give an example of what you are doing in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Open your browser's "Inspector", so you can see which files are being requested. Issues like absolute vs relative should immediately jump out because you'll notice HTTP 404 requests. I checked your site, and it's 404'in because it's trying to load http://www.ra3manifesto.co.nf/css/includes/images/achtergrond.png - relative to your CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Pathing Problems**

One of the issues with using background images this way is that you need to ensure that the path is correct as relative paths will be relative from where the CSS declaration is made.

If you have this style defined in an actual HTML file, then you may want to use an absolute URL (however this can be a fragile approach if your site is subject to being moved) to the image to avoid any issues like this :

```
/* You can use an absolute path to ensure that the proper file is always used */
background-image: url("http://www.yoursite.com/includes/images/achtergrond.png");
```

Otherwise, if you have this style defined in a `.css` file, you can be sure that any paths that are relative to it will always be consistent. Just **ensure that the relative path to your image from your CSS file is correct** :

```
/* Your path may vary, but ensure that it is relative from your CSS file */
background-image: url("../../includes/images/achtergrond.png");
```

**Use the Developer Tools (F12) To Troubleshoot**

Consider using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser to inspect the element in question (via Right-click > Inspect Element). This should allow you to see exactly where the `background-image` attribute is pointing to to verify that it is correct.

**Other Style Issues**

One other issue is that you'll need to ensure that the element you are using the `background-image` property on actually supports it and will show it. Consider using styles like those suggested in [scaisEdge's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36772865/557445) to ensure the element displays the image properly :

```
/* Adding these other styles may help the actual image "appear" 
   if this is not a pathing issue */
.hoofd {
   background: url("{your-path-here}")
   background-size: cover; 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;  
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but one minor correction: absolute *path* starts with / - an absolute URL includes the hostname. Both will work fine, but URL is more fragile (obviously) in case the site moves.

Comment: Good point. I updated the verbiage and added a notation regarding the fragility.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong path, "/" is missing.

It should be:

```
.hoofd {
  background: url("/includes/images/achtergrond.png");
}
```

Comment: I've just pasted the code from his website with correction, so he can see clearly what's the problem.

Comment: rgba, repeat, scroll all have nothing to do with this issue

Comment: It's not about me being happy haha, it's just making sure the answer is accurate without bloating it with unnecessary code.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Wow, so many right answers here with minuses and the post from scaisEdge has wrong answer and has +2...clearly the path is the problem. So many idiots here...

Comment: I have no idea who's downvoted them as I imagine it's either the path issue OR the class is wrong in the HTML or CSS file . Not much else it could be really

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the path to the image is determined relative to the location of your CSS file. If you look in your browser's "Inspector" or "Developer Tools", you'll see that it's trying to load the following:

```
http://www.ra3manifesto.co.nf/css/includes/images/achtergrond.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

The advice people are giving here is correct: either make it an absolute path (ie: starting with a "/"), or first traverse a directory up ("../"). The reason your testing works is because when testing on the webpage itself, the URL is resolved relative to the webpage - not relative to the CSS file.

Answer (score -1):

Using absolute image path:

```
.hoofd {
 background-image: url("/includes/images/achtergrond.png");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think is wrong your CSS style
try:

```
.hoofd {
    display:block;
    background: url("../includes/images/achtergrond.png")
}
```